# agendaView allDaySlot and AllDayText false

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to disable the `allDay` option just in the agenda view. I want it to be visible for the week and month view.

Right now I have this:

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    slotMinutes: 15,
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true
});
```

and another 200 lines of js but here is my initialization of the calendar object.

Can I do something like the following code for the viewObject constructor?

```
view: {
        view:'agendaDay', 
        allDaySlot:false,
        allDayText:false
        },
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are actually looking for Options Setters for fullCalendar. So you can do something like this:

```
viewDisplay: function(view) {
    if( view.name == 'agendaDay' ){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('allDaySlot',false); // Not supported yet
    }
}
```

I've been dreaming about this as well, but unfortunately FullCalendar doesn't allow to set options on fly yet. But the following two links can be useful for you:

http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=293

https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/pull/25